# MPMoviePlayerController swapping videos flicker

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController to play different videos.
However, when I change the video using setContentURL (I'm just targeting OS 3.2 and above), I notice a white flicker.

Is there anyway I can get rid of that flicker and make the transition between videos look smooth?

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Any luck on this yet? I'm having the same issue, and would very much like to see a solution or workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, and I've had this problem too. You could use another instance of the controller, and use an animation to transition from one video to the other, to have a bit more control over the process.